# Android Date To Milles (ISO 8601)

Tags: android, android-widget

am working on countdown widget .The problem is explained below

```
'2012-07-04T15:00:00Z' - >  '1341414000000'

 '1341414000000' - > indicate 2012 july 4th 20:30
```

why this happend? . Am using joda

```
final String format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
            DateTime endTime = formatter.parseDateTime(strDate);
                long diff=endTime.getMillis();
```

Comment: Where are you located?  What local are you running it with?  Most likely, parsing happens in your local but conversion back is on GMT - or the other way around.

Comment: Am in india and i get the from us

Answer (score 0):

```
String time="2012-07-04T15:00:00Z";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      //  time.replace("Z","");
        try {
            Date date=df.parse(time);
            long diff=date.getTime()-System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Date "+diff);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an old question, but I'll answer it anyway, since other people may find this.

In Joda there is a class for ISO 8601 formats, so instead of specifying the format manually you could use that class, as follows:

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

String strDate = "2012-07-04T15:00:00Z";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
DateTime endTime = formatter.parseDateTime(strDate);
long diff=endTime.getMillis();
```

On the other hand, the problem that you seem to be having is related to the time zone. When you convert back from millis to date string, it gets converted using the local time zone. If you want to get the date as UTC, you should do the following:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

DateTime dt = new DateTime(1341414000000).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

It will return 2012-07-04T15:00:00.000Z as expected. If you want to format it without the milliseconds, you can use the same formatter as before:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1341414000000).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
formatter.print(dt)
```

And it will return 2012-07-04T15:00:00Z.